# How to send a http request which uploads a file with params?

Tags: java, httpclient

This is the API I need to use:

[image: obnoxious picture of text]

This is the request by Curl:

```
curl -k -i -X POST --form 'session.id=e7a29776-5783-49d7-afa0-b0e688096b5e' --form 'ajax=upload' --form 'file=@myproject.zip;type=application/zip' --form 'project=MyProject' http://localhost:8443/manager**
```

What I tried:

- I tested the API by Postman and it worked
- i tried to send the request with `httpclient`, but I can't do it, `FileEntity` can send a file, but can't carry other params

How can I use Java to send the request? Which HTTP library can do this?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218785/how-do-i-create-and-post-a-multipart-mixed-http-request-using-apache-httpcompone)

Comment: Thanks a million Abhinav ! which works!!